# Cannot remove selected field in Kibana 8.10.4 Analytics Dashboard Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm currently exploring Kibana analytics visualization, but when I want to remove the already selected field, but there is no option. I have searched and try exploring the menu but can't find one. I expected I can remove the selected field but somehow there's no option to do it. Any suggestion on how I can deselect it?

[image]

I'm using Kibana v8.10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nama.keyword` field is used in the right panel in the "Breakdown" section. On the horizontal axis, you can find a terms aggregation of the `pekerjaan.keyword` field and each column is broken down by the top 3 values of the `nama.keyword` field.

If you want to break down each column by another field, you can simply replace the `nama.keyword` field in the "Breakdown" section. That's how you can "remove" it.